# Нужна ли запятая после слова "некоем"?

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь

Нужна ли запятая во фразе: *находился словно в некоем наполненном воздухом шаре*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Запятая не нужна**, так как местоименное определение *некоем* относится к сочетанию определительного оборота и существительного (неоднородные отношения):

...находился словно **в некоем наполненном воздухом шаре.**

[Розенталь. § 10. Однородные и неоднородные определения](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=98#pp98)

п. 7. Но: чёрные появившиеся на скатерти пятна; заячий наполовину потёртый воротник; большой собранный автором материал и т. п. — первое определение относится к сочетанию второго определения с существительным;

Answer (score 0):

Запятая не нужна. Здесь сравнительный оборот тесно связан со сказуемом (обы*чно в этих случаях сказуемое не выражает необходимого смысла без сравнительного оборота).*

**Ср.: Марья Ильинична сидела как на иголках (П.); Одни как изумруд, другие как коралл (Кр.)  Она сама ходила как дикая (Гонч.);**

Comment: Вы о каком месте в предложении рассуждаете? Перед сравнительным оборотом. т. е. перед словом "словно"? Не думаю, что у кого-то возникли сомнения по этому поводу. Вероятнее, сомнения были по поводу определений (см. ответ @Arina)

Comment: Да, перед словом "словно".

Comment: А вопрос озаглавлен: "Нужна ли запятая после слова “некоем”?"

Comment: Да, после вашего комментария я увидел.

Comment: Но изначально вопрос стоял по-другому.

Comment: Да, вопрос менялся.